# How to let Phoenix live reload ignore temp files?

Tags: emacs, elixir, phoenix-framework, livereload

Emacs generates a temp file when a buffer is being edited, e.g. editing `a.html.eex` would produce `.#a.html.eex`. Unfortunately, since the file extension matches, Phoenix live reload will be triggered on such occasions as well. Is there any way to let live reload ignore such files and thus disable this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the regex in `config/dev.exs` to only match paths not containing `#`.

In `config/dev.exs`, change:

```
~r{web/templates/.*(eex)$}
```

to:

```
~r{web/templates/[^#]*(eex)$}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Do this:

```
~r{web/templates/([^/]+/)*(?!\.\#)[^/]*\.eex$}
```

## Explanation

The [documentation](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload/blob/master/lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex#L27) suggests a regular expression like this:

```
~r{web/templates/.*(eex)$}
```

The problem in our case is that the `.*` part matches anything **including** `/`,
but we need to be able to catch `.#` at the **start** of the filename.

So we do the following:

1. match an initial path fragment `...web/templates`,
2. recurse into subdirectories,
3. ignore anything starting with `.#`
4. accept any file with a `.eex` extension.

Written as an extended regular expression, that's:

```
~r{
  web/templates/
  ([^/]+/)*        # recurse into directories
  (?!\.\#)         # ignore Emacs temporary files (`.#` prefix)
  [^/]*            # accept any file character
  \.eex$           # accept only .eex files
}x
```

Which is what I put in `config/dev.exs`, but, if you want to be more concise, use the regex from the TL;DR